# How to test class methods that rely on associations with RSpec and Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, associations, sinatra

I've written some RSpec tests that successfully create objects with :let statements. However, the test environment doesn't maintain the associations that function properly everywhere else. Below is an example of a class that would turn up a NoMethodError (undefined method `money' for nil:NilClass). Money is a column in Inventory. Any thoughts?

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character

  def self.return_money(character)
    character.inventory.money
  end
end
```

And here's a corresponding example for a spec doc:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Test methods' do
  let(:trader) {
    Character.create(
      name: "Trader",
      location_id: 1)
  }
  let(:trader_inventory) {
    Inventory.create(
       character_id: trader.id,
       storage_capacity: 50000,
       money: 20000,
       markup: 1.35)
  }

  it "test method" do
    expect(Inventory.return_money(trader)).to eq(100)
  end

end
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this method? What's it doing as a class method of Inventory? This is a very strange place to put such a method, especially as it acts on an instance of a completely different type of model.

Comment: i made it up for sake of example. the real method is a bit convoluted but it takes in two characters, checks their inventories/items and executes a transaction between them if valid

Comment: You probably want to make a first-class "Trade" object that can handle that, and some kind of controller that can evaluate if the trade is legit, if it should proceed, and ensure that it was processed correctly.

Comment: That's fair. Scheme aside, is RSpec capable of using associations?

Comment: Rspec is capable of running code. If that code exercises associations, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason this shouldn't work. RSpec isn't special, it's just regular Ruby code. You can confirm this by moving all of your code into a single file, something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => ':memory:')
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :inventory
end

describe 'test' do
  it 'works' do
    puts Character.first.inventory.money.inspect
  end
end
```

Guesses as to what may be broken:

- `money` is a composite field or something like that. Can you post your database schema?
- Library files aren't being loaded correctly. Use `puts $LOADED_FEATURES` to verify that all the files that should be required have been.

Comment: Hey Xavier, circling back to this. Would models/tables need to be explicitly required in spec_helper?

Comment: possibly the model files, yeah. IIRC I don't _think_ Sinatra autoloads the same way that Rails does. (dumping out `$LOADED_FEATURES` in your spec will tell you whether or not the model files have been required)